# Mod_RewriteCond change from Apache 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My host provider is updating to Apache 2.4 and my mod_Rewrite's are failing with the new update. I've read many of the suggestions about modifying the httpd.conf or vhosts.conf however I do not have access to those files on shared hosting, and my provider will not modify to AllowOverride ALL...  does anyone have any modification suggestions of the 2.2 format I am currently using to make compatible with 2.4?

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase   /mod    

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}mod -d [or]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/mod -d [or]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}\\mod -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) inc_page.php?inc_page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) inc_page.php?inc_page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: What's not working in these rules? Can you clarify what is your first rule doing?

Comment: It's returning an internal server error (500). The first rule is rewriting based on if the requested file does not exist but the directory does, or if any of the mod, /mod, and \\mod directories exist. The second rule rewrites based on if the file and directory both do not exist. It runs perfect on Apache 2.2 however it gives me the 500 internal error on 2.4

Comment: For 500 error, can you check Apache's `error.log` file?

Comment: I can and have, nothing is logging from this instance. I purposefully entered info that I knew would fail to test if anything was logging at all, and it is/was. But nothing is logging from this particular rule set, which makes me think nothing is wrong, but something obviously is.  I also added 'Require all granted' but this made no difference. I'm scratching my head at what could be going on.

Comment: Exact same code works fine for me on Apache 2.4. May be you can comment out first `RewriteRule` and all the `RewriteCond` before that and retest.